# Работа с COM-портом в C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, serial, port

В сети есть куча мануалов и примеров по работе с портом в C++, но у меня как-то неохотно они работают. Изначально юзал QSerialPort, все было прекрасно до тех пор, пока случайно не выяснил, что QT-шный `waitForReadyRead()` забагован и кладет мою программу когда ему вздумается.

Решил попробовать поработать с `HANDLE`, но лыжи пока не едут.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //LPCTSTR sPortName = L"COM:6";
    TCHAR *pcCommPort = L"COM:6";
    //serialPort = CreateFile(pcCommPort, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
    HANDLE serialPort = CreateFile( pcCommPort,
                       GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                       0,      //  must be opened with exclusive-access
                       NULL,   //  default security attributes
                       OPEN_EXISTING, //  must use OPEN_EXISTING
                       0,      //  not overlapped I/O
                       NULL ); //  hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices
    if(serialPort==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "open!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
        cout << "cant open! \n";
        cout << lastError << "\n";
    }
    DCB dcbSerialParams;
    FillMemory(&dcbSerialParams, sizeof(dcbSerialParams), 0); //zero initialize the structure
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);      //fill in length

    if (!GetCommState(serialPort, &dcbSerialParams))
    {
        cout << "getting state error\n";
    }

    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_115200;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity=NOPARITY;

    if(!SetCommState(serialPort, &dcbSerialParams))
    {
        cout << "error setting serial port state\n";
    }

    DWORD nb;
    OVERLAPPED ov;
    uint8_t buffer[] = {0xAB, 0x01, 0x02, 0x02, 0x05, 0xFF, 0xF7};
    WriteFile(serialPort,buffer,sizeof(buffer),&nb,&ov);
    CloseHandle(serialPort);
    return 0;
}
```

Если я напишу "COM6", что вполне логично, то порт открыть не получается. Зато спокойно открывает "COM:6" и COM-ы 7, 11, 15 и т.д., которых и в помине нет. Выгрузить и установить настойки скорости, например, тоже не получается -- вываливается ошибка.

Что я делаю не так?

**Edit**:
Прошу прощения, после 2-3 часового тупняка решил спросить здесь от безнадеги. 
Я понял, что открываются все порты, кроме тех, которые реально существуют, проверил `if(..)`, оказалось выдернул где-то неверный код. Должно быть так:

```
if(serialPort!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
    cout << "open!\n";
}
else{
    cout << "cant open! \n";
}
```

Comment: Курите мануалы, там все работает, проверено. И скорости настраиваются, во всяком случае начиная с винды 2000. Только чтобы открыть порты начиная с номера 10 надо как-то хитро их обозвать. То-ли два слеша в начале поставить, то-ли еще чего-то. Сейчас не помню точно, но все есть в интернете.

Comment: Советую написать класс - обертку над API портов, отладить один раз и потом будете пользоваться всю жизнь и горя не знать. Все равно все сторонние поделки это такие же надстройки над виндовским API портов. Хотя сейчас и машин с портами не осталось, только преобразователи COM-USB.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Про хитрости имени COM10+ в курсе, их тоже пробовал. Обновил пост: как обычно, по невнимательности натупил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для открытия порта лучше использовать вот такое имя `port = "\\\\.\\COM2";`
1) с хэндлом сами нашли `if(serialPort!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)`
1.1) Для работы с портом с помощью асинхронного ио необходим флаг `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`
2) Для установки очереди `SetupComm(...)`
3) Для установки таймаутов `SetCommTimeouts(...)`
4) Для установки скоростей/четности и т.п. `SetCommState(...)`
5) Для установки маски событий на порту `SetCommMask(...)`
6) Для выполнения доп. функций `EscapeCommFunction(...)`
7) Для очистки линии `PurgeComm(...)`
8) Для сброса ошибок `ClearCommError(...)`

Для асинхронного ио нужно создавать структуру примерно так:

```
OVERLAPPED m_ovRead;
ZeroMemory(&m_ovRead, sizeof(m_ovRead));
m_ovRead.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, NULL);
```

Ивент этой структуры это собственно то, что будет сигнализировать о завершении операций чтения/записи, дальше эту структуру можно использовать в функциях `GetOverlappedResultEx(...)`

Для чтения можно подписаться на ожидание сигналов на порту с помощью функции `WaitCommEvent(...)`, который вернет вам управление при получении одного из сигналов, заданных в `SetCommMask(...)`

При получении сигнала EV_RXCHAR можно читать из порта.

В общем это основной набор функций для работы с портами, все функции детально описаны на мсдне, даже с приерами. Код получается громоздким, но достаточно написать его 1 раз и любой ком-девайс к вашим услугам.

Comment: Благодарю!
Мое приложение построено на Qt, поэтому решил использовать QSerialPort. Процент таймаутов при длительной работе составлял <2%, с чем я уже смирился. Но смириться с тем, что приложение, заправляющее изделия высоким давлением, может рандомно упасть, как-то не получилось. 
winAPI'шный метод работает с 0% ошибкой и не кладет приложение. Остается класс под него написать и радоваться жизни.

Comment: @MaratGareev Интересно у вас, у меня на ком портах купюро и монетоприемники. 2% таймаутов это много, с помощью винапишных методов вы можете получить детальную информацию о состоянии линии связи и выяснить в чем проблема. Если используете переходник com-usb, то дело может быть в нем. У нас были в работе китайские ноунеймы, которые периодически обрывали соединение, потом перешли на Moxa UPort 1150/1250 и забыли про обрывы.

Answer (score 2):

Прошу прощения, после 2-3 часового тупняка решил спросить здесь от безнадеги. 
Я понял, что открываются все порты, кроме тех, которые реально существуют, проверил `if(..)`, оказалось выдернул где-то неверный код. Должно быть так:

```
if(serialPort!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
    cout << "open!\n";
}
else{
    cout << "cant open! \n";
}
```