# ReadFile теряет данные

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть программно-аппаратный комплекс, состоит из внешнего устройства и ПК с управляющей программой. Связь между устройством и ПК осуществляется по RS232 (точнее USB-RS232). Устройство пишет данные в ПК пачкой 10кБайт, программа получает пачку не полностью, число пропадающих байт варьируется между пусками. Чтение делаю с помощью ReadFile побайтно. При получении данных считаю количество и отправляю снова читать. Фактически получается что буфер вычитан полностью, но данные не все.

В линии RS232 только Rx, Tx, SGND.

Если пачка 15кбайт то программа получает данных больше 10кбайт стабильно, но все равно не все.

HTerm вроде все вычитывает.

Порт настроен с помощью SetCommState 115200, 8 бит, 1 стоп-бит, четности нет, контроля линий нет.

[Работа с COM-портом в C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788381/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-com-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2-c/788457#788457) видел.

> Вопрос собственно в следующем. Полагая что устройство все таки отдает все что положено, где могут теряться данные?

В моем случае видимо какой-то глюк с буфером приема. Увеличение размера принимающего буфера с помощью SetupComm решило проблему.

---

### SetupComm

Функция [SetupComm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setupcomm) устанавливает размеры (в байтах) очередей приема и передачи.

---

[Serial](https://github.com/kraziant/Serial) небольшая библиотека для работы с последовательным портом в Windows, созданная в результате решения вопроса.

Comment: Что стоит в SetupComm ?

Comment: SetupComm не ставил

Comment: Обычно размер буфера стоит порядка килобайта. Возможно, стоит увеличить -  неизвестно, как драйвер USB-COM справляется с большим блоком.

Comment: Вот посмотрел сейчас на свой Prolific в диспетчере устройств - размер буфера в Advanced properties 4 кБ  - и его нельзя увеличить!. В setupComm же обычно 1024 или 2048 размер очереди. Это разные вещи - буфер драйвера и буфер логического устройства.

Comment: Спросил у товарищей, который из железки передавали большой объём данных - всегда при передаче из контроллера режут по кусочкам, десятки и сотни килобайт одной пачкой не проходят.

Comment: SetupComm похоже решает. Установив через SetupComm длину очереди приема чуть больше длинны пакета, данные стали приходить в полном объеме. Из контроллер передают по байтно с просмотром флага «ушло». Проблема была в приемнике. Не ясно как быть если длинна пакета неизвестна. Вечером отредактирую вопрос.

Comment: MBo, напишите про SetupComm я вам хоть ответ засчитаю. Спасибо.

Comment: Может быть, чтение неудачно реализовано? Лучше работать по событию (WaitCommEvent) и читать не по одному байту, а всё, что есть на текущий момент

Comment: @MBo Вот может быть. Сейчас цикл в отдельном потоке и таймер.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кроме настройки порта, стоит установить большую длину очереди с помощью функции [SetupComm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setupcomm).

Размер по умолчанию порядка 1024, Вам нужно увеличить, видимо, до размера пакета.